# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '$implicit') with async pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to find out what is the reason of issue:
[image]

It raises for this part of code:

```html
<div ngbAccordion #accordion="ngbAccordion" >
    <div ngbAccordionItem="first">
      <span class="body-medium-text-l" ngbAccordionHeader>
        <button ngbAccordionButton class="body-medium-text-m">{{ 'hub_repairs_open_requests' | translate }}</button>
      </span>
      <div ngbAccordionCollapse>
        <div ngbAccordionBody>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let return of dataService.returns | async"> <<== here
            <app-repair-row [return ]="return "></app-repair-row>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My investigation yielded no conclusions.

Comment: please share reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Comment: The async pipe returns null directly and then it process the code. So your code need to cover this. Normally it should work with loops but you can try to move the async opterator to a ngIf

Comment: Solution is to use <ng-template> inside <div ngbAccordionBody> and in it the ng-container